# Clicking / opening Kendo UI Toolbar menu from JQuery or Protractor

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, protractor

I have a Kendo UI Toolbar with an "overflow menu" that I need to open from jQuery (or Protractor).  It is the striped button at the far right on the toolbar here:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/toolbar/index

I have tried this, but no go:

```
$('#toolbar > div.k-overflow-anchor.k-button > span').click();
$('#toolbar > div.k-overflow-anchor.k-button > span').trigger('click')
$('#toolbar > div.k-overflow-anchor.k-button > span').trigger('mousedown')
```

**How can I open this menu from jQuery (or Protractor, which is where I will need this)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jQuery in the chrome console, using a mousedown followed by a mouseup works:

```
$('#toolbar > div.k-overflow-anchor.k-button > span').trigger('mousedown')
$('#toolbar > div.k-overflow-anchor.k-button > span').trigger('mouseup')
```

In protractor, what you originally had works for me

```
$('#toolbar > div.k-overflow-anchor.k-button > span').click();
```